# XSLT document('') function doesn't work

Tags: xml, xslt

As I understand from docs, XSLT function document() with empty string as parameter should read current XSLT document. But the following code doesn't work:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <state>test2</state>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      test1
      <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/state"/>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply this XSLT to some XML (just  for example), I have only "test1" as output. Why line

```
 <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/state"/>
```

doesn't print "test2"?

Comment: how are you running the transform?

Comment: works for me. I get both `test1` and `test2` when running through Eclipse XSL Transformer.

Comment: if you're using the MSXML library on Windows, you may need to enable the use of the document function: `styledocument.setProperty("AllowDocumentFunction", true);` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256465.aspx

Comment: I use xalan that is a part of java 6

Comment: Any attempt of running that stylesheet should result in some **error message** like *"Child elements of xsl:stylesheet must be bound to a namespace"*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The definition of document('') is that it reads the XML document whose URI is the same as the base URI of the instruction in the stylesheet containing the document('') call. Unless you use external entities, this is normally the same as the base URI of the stylesheet module. If it doesn't work, this is often because the base URI of the stylesheet module is unknown. This can easily happen if the XSLT processor is given a stylesheet that's in memory (for example as a character string or a DOM) rather than a resource retrieved via a URI. For example, if you use a JAXP StreamSource and don't call setSystemId() then the base URI will be unknown.

Comment: +1 Good answer. In addition, there are some enviroments where the `document()` function could be not allowed for some privilege level.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your own namespace, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="http://localhost"
    exclude-result-prefixes="my">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <my:state>test2</my:state>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>test1</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/my:state"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ouput:

```
test1test2
```

Quoting Michael Kay:

> A user-defined top-level element must
>   also belong to a namespace with a
>   non-null URI, different from the XSLT
>   namespace, and preferably different
>   from the namespace URI used by any
>   vendor. These elements are ignored by
>   the XSLT processor.

Comment: still doesn't work in Java 6 (uses xalan). But anyway thanks, it seems that used version of XSL processor requires some special syntax

Comment: +1 For syntax error. Also, you could quote the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#stylesheet-element): *"In addition, the `xsl:stylesheet` element may contain any element not from the XSLT namespace, provided that the expanded-name of the element has a non-null namespace URI."*