# Can xsl xpath expression read its own template?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-variable

I'm hard-coding the `colspan` value, but could I calculate it from the number of table cells in a row, e.g. using an `xsl:variable`?

The difficulty is in the fact, that the XML nodes contain more attributes than what I'm trying to show using the XSL, so I *CANNOT* reference the XML itself for counting. That's why I'm **wondering if I can reference the html template inside the XSL** instead.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl/allcompanies.xsl"?>
<Companies>
    <row Name="Company One" Address="Grote Markt 1" ZIP="1000" City="BRUSSEL" Country="BE" Telephone="02 261 05 55" Fax="" Email="" />
    <row Name="Company Two" Address="Tielweg 10" ZIP="2803 PK" City="Gouda" Country="NL" Telephone="" Fax="" Email=""/>
    <row Name="Company Three" Address="6 S.Millrock Drive" ZIP="UT 84121" City="Salt Lake City" Country="US" Telephone="+1 801 928 0000" Fax="" Email="" />
</Companies>
```

The XSL:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6">Companies</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>ZIP</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Companies/row">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Address"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@ZIP"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@City"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Country"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Telephone"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
<th colspan="{count(//table/tr[last()]/td)}">Companies</th>
```

but then something that, you know...works.

Knowing full well that what I'm trying here (setting a `colspan`) is, of course, trivial, I'm trying to poke at an underlying question, that of `xslt` applying `XPath` on itself.

Comment: Where does the data for the table cells come from? Please add a sample input XML so that people can actually test it.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I've edited the question to include some sample XML, although I feel inclined to say that, fo this question, it's completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off, but the expression must account for the structure of your input XML:

```
colspan="{count(//Companies/row[last()]/@*)}"
```

In your input XML, there are no `table`, `tr` and `td` elements.

I understand that you attempted to count the table cells that are being generated in your XSLT stylesheet, but this information can be retrieved from your input XML as well and it is more straightforward.

---

Besides, I am wondering why you'd like to count the number of cells dynamically in one place, if you hard-code the attributes that should be turned into table cells in another?

**EDIT**: It turns out that you intended to ask about the theoretical possibility of accessing nodes of the current stylesheet. Yes, there are ways to do this.

**XSLT 1.0**

If you are limited to XSLT 1.0, use the `document()` function, but without specifying an URI to be resolved:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(document('')//td)"/>
```

Michael Kay's "XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference" says:

> [document('')] refers to the stylesheet itself. This construct was often used with XSLT 1.0, where it provided a convenient way to maintain look-up tables in the stylesheet itself.

See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814116/xslt-document-function-doesnt-work) similar SO question.

**XSLT 2.0**

Store information about which attributes should be turned into table cells in an `xsl:variable` element. Then, access its contents both for generating the table and determining the value of the `colspan` attribute.

Actually, this could be done in XSLT 1.0 as well, if you have a means of [converting a result tree fragment to a node-set](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) (e.g. with an EXSLT function).

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that the xml contains more attributes than the html template has table cells per row. I'm trying to get at the table cells in the template themselves, not the ones in the xml!

Comment: Still, you are manually selecting the attributes that should be turned into table cells. So, why do you not manually insert the value for the `colspan` attribute?

Comment: It has little practical use, I admit. It's just to gain insight and find out if it's possible.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the exact direction I wanted. I ended up getting the desired result using `<th colspan="{count(document('')//tr[last()]/td)}">Companies</th>`. My sincere thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Also, I'm glad we finally understood each other.